# How to create an AUD quote if opportunity is in USD?

Tags: quote, multi-currency, quote-template

How to create an AUD quote if opportunity is in USD? I have setup multicurrency to make this happen and wants to use the standard quote functionality of SF.

Any help is appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: if you have multi-currency enabled, why not make the Oppo currency AUD? all rollups of Oppo in reports/dashboards will rollup in your corporate currency.

Comment: Because our team keeps a pricebook in USD (we want to keep it this way) and issues quotes based on an exchange rate that occasionally changes. Moreover, our corporate currency is in EU. Any thoughts?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are swimming against the tide here. As @sfdcfox says, OOB SFDC currency works in a certain way and for good reason as Quote line items can be sync'd to Opportunity line items.  Normally, one has a pricebook defined in all transactable currencies.

Now, if you want to still go ahead:

- You'll need to use a custom `Quote__c` object
- You'll need to prompt the user for the currency; perhaps defaulted to the Oppo currency
- You'll have to build your own 'add' Quote Item VF page with an ability to convert PriceBookEntries in USD to the Quote currency.
- Once the quote is issued, and if you want the quote value in AUD to be reflected in `Oppo.Amount` in the Oppo currency, you'll need to build your own quote -> Oppo sync and currency conversion logic.
- You'll need your own quote PDF generator and quote PDF attach feature.

Answer (score 2):

Per the [documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api.meta/api/sforce_api_objects_quote.htm):

> CurrencyIsoCode
>
> ### Type
>
> picklist
>
> ### Properties
>
> Defaulted on create, Filter, Restricted picklist
>
> ### Description
>
> Available only for organizations with the multicurrency feature enabled. Contains the ISO code for any currency allowed by the
> organization.
>
> If the organization has multicurrency and a Pricebook2Id specified on
> the quote, then the currency value of this field must match the
> currency of the PricebookEntry objects that are associated with any
> quote line items it has.
>
> This value is copied from the related Opportunity and can't be
> changed.

Note that the Currency must be the same as the opportunity, and the PriceBook2Id must also match that currency.

This is all baked in to the standard quote system. You won't be able to subvert multi-currency in the way you'd like.

Comment: Awwww I understand, however, is this possible with custom coding/development?

Comment: @GieAdkins There's organizations out there that have built their own Quote systems; I used to work for one that had a product that included quoting (before Quotes were actually a thing). That said, I don't believe the development time and maintenance time would be worth it just for a single feature like this. You might want to sit down and think things through about how you can work with the system instead of against it.